# Detect end of reloadData method in UITablewView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

Is there any way of detecting the end of the reloadData method in UITableView ?

I can use the viewDidAppear for the initial call but after that I have no way of detecting the end of a reloadData.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is nothing in the documentation and the `UITableViewDelegate` is of no help either. In theory, what you could do, is subclass UITableView and override the reloadData method like so:

```
- (void)reloadData
{
    // reload data starts
    [super reloadData];

    // and here reload data ended..
}
```

Unless reloadData spawns some separate background threading, this marks the end of reloadData.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the reloadData method triggers execution in the UI thread so this kind of approach does not work. What I want is to be notified about the end of the reloading of the data in the table.

Comment: There is some information about the inexistence of a callback for reloadData back in 2008 http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1664015. Any news since...